# All USB 3.0 devices spontaneously disconnecting at the same time

Tags: windows-10, usb, motherboard

I have a desktop computer with a lot of external storage devices and peripherals. I usually don't have any problems but recently when booting my computer or trying to do work all of my USB 3.0 and type C ports will disconnect all USB devices at the same time. My USB 2.0 ports will do the same thing but only for a second before the devices in those ports reconnect. Usually, only 1/4 times will the 3.0 ports will start working again on their own.

I have tried leaving Device Manager open so I can see if the USB controllers are disconnecting and I have noticed an "Unknown USB Device (Set Address Failed)" under USB controllers. I can't tell what USB device it's for and I don't see that when everything is working normally.

Here is a list of all of my devices:

USB 3.0:

- 7 port self-powered USB 3.1 HUB

  - Corsair K95 RGB keyboard
  - Corsair RGB mouse
  - Logitec webcam
  - USB 3.0 thumb drive
- External hard drive hub that supports two SATA drives and has its own power supply

  - Contains 1 5400RPM HDD and 1 SSD
    USB 2.0:
- USB microphone
- Elgato Streamdeck
- Two USB extention calbes with 2.4gz adapters for game controllers.

Normally in the past, I have two 3.5" HDDs in the external SATA HUB (one inactive and one active) without any problem. Right now I'm trying to clone from the HDD to the SSD and it works fine for about 2-3 minutes before everything disconnects. This is also not the first time doing a clone with this setup. When I turn off the external SATA HUB 1/3 times everything else will reconnect. Sometimes some devices will but other devices like my mouse will remain disconnected. When this does happen I can still use the functionality of my USB 2.0 devices like my Streamdeck and I am able to plug devices in other USB 2.0 ports and windows will recognize them just fine. It just seems to be my 3.0 ports.

I'm wondering if there is a power limit or if Windows cannot handle activity from so many USB 3.0 devices. Which doesn't make a whole lot of sense because I currently am using only 10 devices and most of them have their own dedicated port on my motherboard. Also restarting my PC does not seem to fix the issue. I am wondering if I could be an issue with my motherboard because about three months ago I had an M.2 SSD that stopped working and I discovered that it was my motherboard because the M.2 worked in other systems and other M.2 drives did not work in my motherboard.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte Aorus Gaming 3.

EDIT:

I also noticed that under Human Interface Devices in Device Manager, all of my HID-compliant consumer control device will show a yellow triangle when this event occurs.

Comment: "will disconnect all USB devices at the same time" - This sounds like an issue where you don't have enough resources.  Do you get any sort of notification from Windows that is the case?  I only ever experienced this issue when I was not using an externally powered USB Hub.  Is that the case here?  How many devices are we talking about?  What are the power requirements of these devices?  What do you mean by "self-powered"?

Comment: @Ramhound I do not get any windows notification when this happens. By self-powered, I mean that those devices are not receiving power through the USB port and have their own external power supply. I only have about 10 USB devices altogether including USB 3.0 and 2.0. I am unsure of the power requirements of the USB HUB and External SATA HUB but they have their own power supplies so it doesn't matter. Devices connected to the USB 3.0 HUB with the power supply receive their power from the USB hub and not my motherboard.

Comment: "Two USB extension cables" - How long are these extension cables.  The only times I had this problem is when I used extension cables instead of cables that were simply long enough to connect the USB Hub where I wanted it.  I also split the work between two different internal HUBs by connecting two different USB externals hubs to them.  (1-7x2 basically).

Comment: @Ramhound Both cables are about 3 feet long. Although I'm not using my hub with them. Just wireless adapters for game controllers. The USB hub is connected directly to my motherboard. The HUB only has my keyboard, mouse, webcam, and a 16gb USB stick connected to it. So not much data is going between my motherboard and the hub. Everything else is, including the extension cables are using their own dedicated port on my motherboard. But like I said, the 2.0 ports usually only have a second of downtime so my game controllers do work with the extension cables.

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: @Ramhound As specified in my question, I have a Gigabyte Aorus Gaming 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93978/discussion-between-ramhound-and-lucas).

Answer (score 2):

Disable 'automaticaly power off USB devices when not in use' in the power options.